# How to prevent drag event when click on drop-down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Muuri.js (https://github.com/haltu/muuri) to utilize the drag and drop feature and I put a drop-down inside the grid class.

However, every time I clicked on the drop-down, it triggered the drag event.
Any ideas how to prevent it?

This is my html code:

```
<div class="row mh grid">
    <div class="col-sm-6 itemgrid" id="div-1">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="panel-white">
                <h3 class="panel-title" style="display:inline-block;">Chart 1</h3>
                <select ng-change="changeChartType(selectedType)" ng-model="selectedType" >
                    <option ng-repeat="t in chartType" value={{t.type}}>{{t.dispName}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-type="selectedType" chart-data="data1" chart-labels="labels1"  chart-options="options" width="600" height="200" chart-colors="colors" style="cursor: default;"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my js code:

```
var grid = new Muuri('.grid', {
        dragEnabled: true
    });
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's an issue with [Event Propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation). Which can be stopped with [`event.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) so that the the drag handler is not triggered.

### ES6

```
let cardDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.card select');
for (let dropdown of cardDropdowns) {
    dropdown.addEventListener('click', evt => {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

### ES5

```
var cardDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.card select');
for (var i = 0; i < cardDropdowns.length; i++) {
    cardDropdowns[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Just add this:

```js
dragStartPredicate: {
      distance: 10,
      delay: 100
}
```

[dragStartPredicate](https://github.com/haltu/muuri?tab=readme-ov-file#grid-option-dragstartpredicate)